# Next JS input with character mapping does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, next.js

in characterMapping.js this types of mapping is there:

```js
[
  "[": "ख्", A: "ा", k: "ा",
  /* making half characters complete */
  "[A": "ख",
  "[k": "ख",
]
```

and inside the handleInputchange function of Hinditypingspace.jsx  I need logic to implement it.  here is the logic:

```
if (char === "[") {
  const nextChar = inputValue[i + 1];
  if (nextChar === "A" || nextChar === "k") {
    newInput = newInput.slice(0, -1); // Remove the previous "["
    newInput += characterMapping[char + nextChar] || char + nextChar;
    i += 1; // Skip the next character ("A" or "k")
  } else {
    newInput += characterMapping[char] || char;
  }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWZ7N.png)

When I click [ and then k or A i was expecting it to be ख as per the characterMapping but i am getting ख्ा.